# Using the $N - \varepsilon$ definition to find the limit of a sequence

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, limits

Yesterday I had a post about this, and it cleared a lot up; however, even though I feel like I understand how to go about solving problems like this, I don't seem to get the right answers. For example:

$u_n = \frac{2n+3}{2n+1}$. We know that this sequence converges to 1, but I want to prove it using the definition.

So I want to show that , $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ where,$ n > N \implies u_n - 1 < \varepsilon$.

We can manipulate the expression such that $u_n = \frac{2n+3}{2n+1} =\frac{n}n \frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2+\frac{1}n} = \frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2+\frac{1}n}$

Thus, we can show that $\forall \varepsilon > 0$, $\exists N$ where,$ n > N \implies \frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2+\frac{1}n} - 1 < \varepsilon$

Now, we can say that 0 < $\frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2+\frac{1}n}$ < $\frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2} = 1 + \frac{3}{2n}$.
We can use this logic to say that

$\frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2+\frac{1}n} - 1 < 1 + \frac{3}{2n} - 1 < \varepsilon$ (since $1 + \frac{3}{2n}$ converges to 1).

So, finding an $N$ for $\frac{3}{2n} - 1$ would be the same as finding an $N$ for $u_n$, so we do:

$1 + \frac{3}{2n} - 1 < \varepsilon$ is the same as $\frac{3}{2n} < \varepsilon$.
Thus, if $ N > \frac{3}{2\varepsilon}$, then the initial implication follows. However, I'm not sure how to complete things from here; am I close, or did I fall off the rails at some point? Thanks.

Comment: you're done, you constructed the $N$ corresponding to an arbitrary positive $\epsilon$. if you want to be very very formal, substitute $N$ into $u_n$ and show $u_n-1<\epsilon$.

Comment: @TonyS.F. But don't I have to show that my $N$ works?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have already shown that your $N$ works, I think it's all the notation that is giving you a headache. I would write like this (these are your words, but rewritten):

Given $\varepsilon$, take any $N > \frac{3}{2\epsilon}$. Now, for any $n >N$, we have $$ \frac{3}{2n} < \varepsilon$$

and so,

$$\left|\frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2+\frac{1}n} - 1\right| < \left|1 + \frac{3}{2n} - 1\right| = \frac{3}{2n} < \varepsilon $$

Comment: Thanks for your answer. So should I be adding this to the end of my proof, right? Just as a formality more than anything else, since by doing all that manipulation, I have proved that my $N$ works?

Comment: Sure, if you want. I'd say that the tricky thing about $\epsilon - \delta$ (or $N$) is that often, we don't show (and don't have to show) how we found the $\delta/N$ corresponding to our $\epsilon$, we just state which one to pick. Sometimes teachers want to see these calculations, but they are not required for a formal proof.

Comment: Fair enough. But surely after stating it you still have to show that it holds, no? Or is it usually obvious?

Comment: Absolutely, we have to show that it holds, and it doesn't have to be obvious. That's how these things go: Pick any $\epsilon$, show that for that arbitrary, but fixed, $\epsilon$, we can produce an $N$ such that $|f(n) -L| < \epsilon$ for $n > N$. So we do sneaky calculations behind the scenes, so that we know which $N$ to choose. And then we show that $|f(n) -L| < \epsilon$ holds for $n > N$. This last part is often the "meat" of the proof. It is certainly important. Is this clear?

Comment: Ah, I see what you're saying. In a test/homework setting though, I assume they'd like to see how I reached my $N$. However, in practical situations, finding it is rather trivial, but showing that it holds is crucial. Is that correct?

Comment: Yeah, if you want to show that you understand what you're doing, I'm sure the teacher will be happy. If you LaTeX it, even better! People like nice typesetting. In my experience, it's almost always the other way around, finding the $N$ that works can be really hard, but once you have it, proving that it works is often easy. Look at your own example. Finding the $N$ took all those calculations. But showing that it works was rather easy, right?

Comment: I'm sorry, poor choice of words on my part. I meant relatively unimportant rather than trivial. I have a follow-up question, if you don't mind. If you do all the sneaky calculations behind the scenes, then how can you show that it all follows logically. Surely, if i just written down the last four lines from your answer, that woudln't be enough, no?

Comment: Everything from "Given $\epsilon$" and down, is enough for a formal proof. The proof is consistent, in the sense that every line follows from what came before, with no extra info needed. The ONLY magical thing is how I (you, actually) came up with the proper $N$. This is what the sneaky calculations give, but you don't have to show them for a formal proof, they don't contribute the logic of the proof in any way.

Comment: Putting it another way. In my proof, the last line shows that $|f(n) -L| < \epsilon$, for my choice of $N$, corresponding to your choice of $\epsilon$. We don't need anything else.

Comment: I would have thought that I would need to at least prove the equivalence between $u_n$ and $\frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2+\frac{1}n}$, and the equivalence between $\frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2}$ and $1 + \frac{3}{2n}$, just to make things clear. Other than that, I think I totally understand. Thanks a lot for being patient with me and answering all my questions, I really appreciate it. Have a great day!

Comment: I'm sorry, I've been staring at too many $\epsilon$'s, Of course, you have to show that $u_n = \frac{2+\frac{3}n}{2+\frac{1}n}$, I have omitted this in my proof, since you motivated it so well, but you're right, for clarity, it would be better to put it in. Glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2):

It might be useful to rewrite the expression in question before doing "epsilontic":

$$u_n = \frac{2n+3}{2n+1} = \frac{2n+1+2}{2n+1}= 1+\frac{2}{2n+1}$$

Now,
$$u_n - 1 = \frac{2}{2n+1} \lt \frac{2}{2n}= \frac{1}{n}$$
From here. you can surely find your $N_{\varepsilon}$ easily.

Answer (score 2):

The answer of @JuliusL33t is right on the nose.

But I want to show how you could have arranged your work and derived a value for $N$ in a way that allows you to close off the proof more smoothly (this will be a different value of $N$).

The idea is to work backwards from the inequality $|u_n-1| < \epsilon$, rewriting it in equivalent form as you go along (if that is possible, which for this problem it is).

Start with the inequality
$$(1) \qquad |u_n - 1| < \epsilon
$$
By substitution, inequality (1) is logically equivalent to
$$(2) \qquad \bigg| \frac{2n+3}{2n+1} - 1 \bigg| < \epsilon
$$
By the laws of algebra, inequality (2) is logically equivalent to
$$(3) \qquad \bigg| \frac{2}{2n+1} \biggr| < \epsilon
$$
Since $n$ is a positive integer, the fraction inside the absolute value signs is positive, and so we may strip off the absolute value signs, to get a logically equivalent inequality
$$(4) \qquad \frac{2}{2n+1} < \epsilon
$$
By the laws of inequality, (4) is logically equivalent to
$$(5) \qquad n > \frac{2-\epsilon}{2\epsilon}
$$
Now take any $N > \frac{2-\epsilon}{2\epsilon}$. If $n > N$ then (5) is true, and so each of the logically equivalent inequalities (4), (3), (2), (1) is true, hence $|u_n-1|<\epsilon$ is true.

Comment: I really did miss the obvious here. I'll make sure see if I can't simplify $u_n - l$ in the future, before doing all the overcomplicated stuff. The step-by-step process makes things clearer, I'll be sure to break down my limit-proofs like that. Thanks a lot for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I think you are giving yourself too much work here.

Straightforwardly $u_n-1=\frac {2}{2n+1}$ and if $\frac 2{2n+1} \lt \epsilon$ we have $n\gt  \frac 1{\epsilon}-\frac 12$

This is reversible, so this will find you a candidate for $N$

Comment: Well I feel stupid. I should have looked at this before forcing my way through everything. Although, it is good to know that I have the general concept down. Thanks!